# Jquery overwrite my "this" in my object

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback), but I was unable to find it here according to my problem description. A lot of people could have the same issue.

I have an object like:

```
var my_object = new function() {

    this.function2 = function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
           this.function1()
        })
    };

    this.function1 = function() {
    };

}

a = my_object()
```

If I click the #button this happen

> this.function1 is not a function

How to correctly solve this issue? How to prevent jquery from overwriting my "this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store  a reference to `this` to avoid confusion and context problems.

Within the event handler `this` is something completely different .. it is a dom node

```
var my_object = new function() {
    var self = this; // reference to `my_object`

    self.function2 = function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
           // "this" is dom element returned by jQuery event handler
           // but "self" is already a stored reference to `my_object`
           self.function1()
           $(this).css('color','red')
        })
    };

    self.function1 = function() {
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you bind an event handler in jQuery, `this` inside the callback refers to the element the event has been fired on.

To set the value of `this` in a function, call `bind` on the function, passing the object you would like to become `this`:

```
var my_object = new function() {

  this.function2 = function() {
      $("#button").click(function() {
         this.function1()
      }.bind(this)
  });

  this.function1 = function() {
  };

}
```